# What sapui5 controls to use to build the following interface?

Tags: sapui5

I got a requirement to build a table that should look like

**Desired Interface**
[image]

Where start time and End time will have `TimePicker` input fields. Can someone please suggest how to achieve this interface( what controls to use or maybe an example in jsfiddle would be highly appreciated) Thanks in Advance

Here is what i have so far:

```
        <Table id="idNonRosterTable" inset="false" items="{schedule>/}">
            <columns>
                <Column hAlign="Center"/>
                <Column hAlign="Center">
                    <Text text="Monday"/>
                </Column>
                <Column hAlign="Center">
                    <Text text="Tuesday"/>
                </Column>
                <Column hAlign="Center">
                    <Text text="Wednsday"/>
                </Column>
                <Column hAlign="Center">
                    <Text text="Thursday"/>
                </Column>
                <Column hAlign="Center">
                    <Text text="Friday"/>
                </Column>
                <Column hAlign="Center">
                    <Text text="Total hours per week"/>
                </Column>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle" >
                    <cells>
                        <ObjectIdentifier title="{schedule>week}"/>
                        <HBox>
                            <VBox><Text text="Start time"/><TimePicker valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm"/><Text text="Total Hrs/Day"/></VBox>
                            <VBox><Text text="End time"/><TimePicker valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm"/><Text/></VBox>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox>
                            <VBox><Text text="Start time"/><TimePicker valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm"/><Text text="Total Hrs/Day"/></VBox>
                            <VBox><Text text="End time"/><TimePicker valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm"/><Text/></VBox>
                        </HBox>
                            <HBox>
                            <VBox><Text text="Start time"/><TimePicker valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm"/><Text text="Total Hrs/Day"/></VBox>
                            <VBox><Text text="End time"/><TimePicker valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm"/><Text/></VBox>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox>
                            <VBox><Text text="Start time"/><TimePicker valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm"/><Text text="Total Hrs/Day"/></VBox>
                            <VBox><Text text="End time"/><TimePicker valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm"/><Text/></VBox>
                        </HBox>
                            <HBox>
                            <VBox><Text text="Start time"/><TimePicker valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm"/><Text text="Total Hrs/Day"/></VBox>
                            <VBox><Text text="End time"/><TimePicker valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm"/><Text/></VBox>
                        </HBox>
                        <Text/>
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like nested for loop with sap.ui.table.Table, addColumn() and addRow()